# Images only shows src with CKeditor

Tags: php, database, mysqli, ckeditor, kcfinder

After days of searching for my answer, i could not find anything that solved my problem.

I am currently making a custom small 'cms' for a website. I am using CKeditor and KCfinder for it. The problem is that I cannot add images on the webpage. All of the images are shown in the CKeditor, but when I save the changes, only an image src is shown on the front-end.

My currently echo in php is

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($typebox1)){
    echo $row['box1'];
    }
?>`
```

Where the echoed row is a database TEXT with some text and an image src.

I allowed image tags in the congifure.js file with

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'img[src,alt,width,height]';
```

and add some script to replace the normal textarea

```
window.onload = function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'box1',
    {
    toolbar : 'basic',
    uiColor : '# 9AB8F3',
    enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
    });

    CKEDITOR.replace( 'box2',
    {
    toolbar : 'basic',
    uiColor : '# 9AB8F3',
    enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
    });
};
```

But none of this all seems to work. If someone need further code just ask! I would appreciate every little step to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem now. I needed to add htmlspecialchars_decode and htmlentities on the echoes to display the image correctly. CKEditor inserted &codes into the database, which made some problems.

Comment: could you elaborate on that